# 2-edge-connectivity and Hamiltonian Cycles

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Is a 2-edge-connected graph necessarily Hamiltonian? I would think you could write any 3-edge-connected component of the graph as a union of cycles and construct a Hamiltonian cycle across the cut set that way. Anybody have a counter example? I'm having trouble convincing myself this is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n+1}$. This is certainly 2-edge-connected (in fact, I believe it is $n$-edge-connected) but it does not have a Hamiltonian cycle by a parity argument: any cycle must alternate between the two parts of the bipartition, but one of the parts has more vertices than the other.